# .hta file with JS works well but once donwloaded doesn't work anymore

Tags: linux, windows, file, hta

Almost everything is in the title.

I built a very simple hta file with a JS script that get the username.

The hta file works fine but once i download the exact same file from a Linux server, the hta file doesn't work anymore.

However if i open the downloaded file with a text editor and just save it, then the hta file works again!!

Here is an example of the js script:

```
<script>
    var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
    var uname =  objUserInfo.UserName;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "http://localhost:8000/"+uname, true);
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

The md5 hash of the file on my windows machine and on the linux machine are exactly the same.

Do you have an idea about that? I really would like my hta file works once downloaded.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post minimal example code? Does it have "the mark of the web" NTFS stream?

Comment: If you right-click and view the properties of the file that does not work, does it have a "Unlock"/"FromTheWeb" button?

Comment: nope, no Unlock/FromTheWeb button

Comment: Have you tried adding the Linux site's domain name to your Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer -> Tools menu -> Internet Options -> Security tab? 

The file's source Zone is stored in the NTFS Alternate Data Stream, which you can read from Powershell:     `Get-Item c:\yourscript.hta -stream * `

Comment: It's likely the file encoding differences between Linux and Windows, although if it was encoding wouldn't expect the MD5 hash to match. Likely similar issue to [Windows to Linux utf-8 file](//stackoverflow.com/a/2466746).

Comment: If you are using PHP to serve the file from Linux I'd suggest piping the file download through a PHP script that adds the UTF-8 BOM as it streams the file to be downloaded - ref [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4440143).